# I have tried many times but i am not getting any solution for htaccess.I want-------

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have tried to rewrite this url using htaccess:

```
 http://php4u.in/list.php?link=art+galleries&city=Jaipur&area=adarsh+nagar

                to

http://php4u.in/art+galleries/Jaipur/adarsh+nagar
```

If any friend has solution for this please share me. thanx alot

Comment: Please let us know what have tried yet

Comment: @Aditya: You wrote you have tried many times. Can you show one of those attempts?

Comment: I have done url rewrite  using:
 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ list.php?link=$1&city=$2&area=$3 [PT,L,QSA] .


but css is not loading after url write.please give me any solution of this